# Custom UI Interactor (XR Interaction Toolkit)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, virtual-reality

I'm working on a VR project and like with other VR projects I've worked on, UI is an issue. I've never been able to find a good solution for UI Interaction. The best I've come up with is placing 3D colliders on the UI elements and shooting a Physics Raycast. Obviously not ideal.

And so I was very excited when I learned that the XR Interaction Toolkit contains systems that solve this problem. But the XR Ray Interaction & XR Interactor Line Visual Component are not customizable enough for what I want (Fair enough, it is a preview package after all.)

So I would like to make my own UI Interaction component that works the same way as the XR Ray Interactor (in the sense that it works as seamlessly with UI as a mouse cursor would.)

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I find useful for me to represent UI elements positioning logic in [(pitch, yaw)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes) coordinates for 360-panorama style UI (when elements are on a sphere around viewer). It is comfortable to me as it allows to abstract away from redundant Z-axis in camera space. Object's form looks same no matter how far the object is from camera and its scale, if all its vertices keep their (pitch, yaw) angular positions. Also click-picking an object is very easy to calculate this way (you don't need any ray casting, just check (pitch, yaw) as you check for (y, x) in 2D UI, just keep in mind to workaround wrapping around 360 degrees).

[image]